# Javascript: How to test if response JSON array is empty

Tags: json, jquery

I'm getting back the following JSON:

```
{"array":[],"object":null,"bool":false}
```

And I'm testing it with the following, seemingly exhaustive, if statement:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/rest/siteService/list",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var siteArray = response.array;

            // Handle the case where the user may not belong to any groups
            if (siteArray === null || siteArray=== undefined || siteArray=== '' || siteArray.length === 0) {
                            window.alert('hi');
            }
       }
});
```

But the alert is not firing.  :[

Comment: What does `console.log(siteArray)` show you?

Comment: [].  I tried if siteArray === "[]" but that didn't work either

Comment: An empty array is not the same as `null`, `undefined`, et al.

Comment: .length === 0 doesn't catch it either tho

Comment: What does `console.log(siteArray.length)` show you?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [$.isArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/) to check whether an object is an array. Then you can check the truthness of the `length` property to see whether it is empty.

```
if( !$.isArray(siteArray) ||  !siteArray.length ) {
    //handler either not an array or empty array
}
```

Comment: That did it, and it's much more elegant

Comment: That's an unfortunate resolution to the question.  Why does this work but OP's code didn't?

Answer (score 7):

Two empty arrays are not the same as one another, for they are not the same object.

```
var a = [];
if (a === []){
  // This will never execute
}
```

Use `if (siteArray.length==0)` to see if an array is empty, or more simply `if (!siteArray.length)`

Comment: @Dennis Good point, it was scrolled off the window and I didn't see it. Nonetheless, it will work for an empty array. More data is needed :/

Comment: I was wondering why my comparison wasn't working. That makes a lot of sense thank you.