# jQuery Ajax Json response - check if is null

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am getting data from MySQL using jQuery Ajax and JSON. However I need to know when the response is empty. I passe a date parameter to my php that will return some data or not... depending on date.

My Javascript code (simple version):

```
function pac_irra(date){
    .ajax({
            url: 'get_db_data/pac_irra.php?date='+date,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {get_values: true},
            beforeSend: function(){
            $("#morris-line-chart").append(load_img);
            },
            success: function(response) {

                date =  response[0].Timestamp;
                $('#a1').append(date);
            },
        });
    }
```

If for example I used yesterday (2015-09-26) data I get the following json data (only a part of it):

```
[{"Timestamp":"2015-09-26 16:50:00","pac":"35.20","irra":"38.97"},{"Timestamp":"2015-09-26 17:00:00","pac":"32.19","irra":"35.51"}]
```

Now, for example, if I chose a date without data it returns:

```
[]
```

In my javascript code below I would like to add a if statement to my success function in case of json array is empty... something like:

```
 function pac_irra(date){
        .ajax({
                url: 'get_db_data/pac_irra.php?date='+date,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {get_values: true},
                beforeSend: function(){
                $("#morris-line-chart").append(load_img);
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    date =  response[0].Timestamp;
                    $('#a1').append(date);
                 if ( ***array is empty***) {
                         ('#a1').append('No data');
                    };
                },
            });
        }
```

In my success function I have a morris chart created with the json data... I don't put it in the code...

So how do I check if it's empty? I already made a lot of attempts:

```
if (response.length == 0)
```

or another attempt

```
if (response[0].Timestamp == "") or if (!response)
```

And nothing works... I still can't check if the json array is empty...

My php code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/database/db_connect.php";
    include_once($path);
    if(isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $days = $_GET['days'];      

        $var = array();  
        $query = "SELECT CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(Date,' ',pac.Time), 'UTC', 'Europe/Lisbon' ) as Timestamp, ROUND((pac.Value/6440)*100,2) pac, ROUND((irra.Value/1000)*100,2) irra
        FROM AggData pac
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Time, Value 
        FROM AggData WHERE Date=DATE_ADD('$date',INTERVAL '$days' DAY) and idEquipment=5 and idMeasure=6 ) irra 
        ON pac.Time=irra.Time 
        Where pac.Date=DATE_ADD('$date',INTERVAL '$days' DAY) and pac.idEquipment=1 and pac.idMeasure=3
        AND (irra.Value>0 or pac.Value>0)
        Order BY pac.Time asc
        " or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 
        $result = $link->query($query); 
        while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $var[] = $obj;
        }
    echo json_encode($var);
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use response.length == 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350604/javascript-how-to-test-if-response-json-array-is-empty

Comment: `var rep = JSON.parse(response); if(rep != null || rep == "")`

Comment: aldrin27 not work :(

Comment: Why not check if query result is null before sending response in the backend? Then send back a string "No result Found" if it is null along with a status error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below if will check various condition

```
   if((response && jQuery.isArray(response))?(response.length==0?false:(jQuery.isPlainObject(response[0])?!jQuery.isEmptyObject(response[0]):response[0])):response){

       //console.log("adfdsaf");
    }
```

if it will check if
response is null or undefined
or response == []
or response == [{}] or response[""]

I think this is the problem

```
    success: function(response) {
             if((response && jQuery.isArray(response))?(response.length==0?false:(jQuery.isPlainObject(response[0])?!jQuery.isEmptyObject(response[0]):response[0])):response){
                   ('#a1').append('No data');
               }else{
                   date =  response[0].Timestamp;
                   $('#a1').append(date);

                }  
                };
            },
```

hopefully it will work

Comment: I've tried your code... but nothing happens 

    if((response && jQuery.isArray(response))?(response.length==0?false:(jQuery.isPlainObject(response[0])?!jQuery.isEmptyObject(response[0]):response[0])):response){
     if (response == [] || response == [{}] || response[""]) {   
     $('#chart_title').append('No data!');
     };

Comment: Can you please send me the response, which you are receiving. just print it with console.log(response). Maybe you are getting the response in this format "[]" in string. If you send me it would be gr8 help to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Found a problem.. function(response) {
                    date =  response[0].Timestamp;
                    $('#a1').append(date);
                 if ( ***array is empty***) ........ since we are not checking whether response is undefined or null.. and trying to retreive the Timestamp.. response[0].Timestamp..

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it out, since we are trying to retreive the response[0].Timestamp, in success block, without checking the response whether it's empty or not, that's why we were getting error